# error: duplicate class while compiling java project with Gradle containing dagger generated sources

Tags: java, gradle, dagger-2

I'm building a Java project using Gradle for build the project and Dagger2 as dependency injector. And I'm getting this error:

```
<path to the class>/MyModule_SourceConnectionDTOFactory.java:12: error: duplicate class: <package>.MyModule_SourceConnectionDTOFactory
public final class MyModule_SourceConnectionDTOFactory implements Factory<ConnectionDTO> {
             ^
<path to the class>/MyModule_DestinationConnectionDTOFactory.java:12: error: duplicate class: <package>.MyModule_DestinationConnectionDTOFactory
public final class MyModule_DestinationConnectionDTOFactory
             ^
```

Java version 1.8
Gradle version: 5.4.1 (also tried with 4.5.1)

Dagger dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.17'
    ...
}
```

Module Class:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    private final MyConfiguration config;

    @Inject
    public MetaStoreModule(MyConfiguration config){
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("sourceConnection")
    public ConnectionDTO sourceConnectionDTO() {
        return new ConnectionDTO(config.sourceHost(), config.sourceUser(),
                config.sourcePassword(), config.sourceDataBaseName());
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("destinationConnection")
    public ConnectionDTO destinationConnectionDTO() {
        return new ConnectionDTO(config.destinationHost(), config.destinationUser(),
                config.destinationPassword(), config.destinationDataBaseName());
    }
}
```

Component class:

```
import dagger.Component;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
public interface MyComponent{
    @Named("sourceConnection")
    ConnectionDTO sourceConnectionDTO();
    @Named("destinationConnection")
    ConnectionDTO destinationConnectionDTO();
}
```

If I just have one component annotated with that name, not sure why it is finding a duplicate class

Comment: Dagger is currently at `2.23.2`, you might wanna try to upgrade the version.

Comment: I can't because of project dependencies with libraries and other company policies... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, seems that this plugin for idea:

```
    apply plugin: "idea"
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDir new File("src", 'main/generated')
    sourceSets.test.java.srcDir new File("src", 'test/generated_tests')
    idea {
        module {
            // Marks the already(!) added srcDir as "generated"
            generatedSourceDirs += file('src/main/generated')
            generatedSourceDirs += file('src/test/generated_tests')
        }
    }
```

Was causing the error. Removed it and fix the issue, still not sure why it causes it when it works in other projects with the same Gradle version.